# Os.system and mysql restore not working in python unittest

Tags: python, mysql, windows, python-unittest, os.system

I am doing a unit test for a program that saves entries in a database "mydatabase". Therefore, I need to restore the db once I test each function so that the other tests are not compromised. I tried to use os.system() to write a mysql command to restore. Below is the relevant part of the program:

```
class testSql(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self,
        dbName = "mydatabase",
        existingUser = "John",
        nonExistingUser = "thisnamedoesnotexist",
    ):
        os.system('mysql -u root -ppassword mydatabase < "mypath/schema.sql"')
        self.dbName = dbName
        self.existingUser = existingUser
        self.nonExistingUser = nonExistingUser

    def test_signUp(self):
        self.assertFalse(sql.userExists(self.nonExistingUser))
        sql.signUp(self.nonExistingUser,"password")
        self.assertTrue(sql.userExists(self.nonExistingUser))
```

When I run the program, however, instead of showing the result of the test, I only see the result from the mysql command, and the terminal freezes, so I can't enter anything and am forced to close it: [Result from terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ry0EW.png)

What I tried: making a function with the os.system and calling it; importing a file with that function; using the exec() function to execute a file with the statement; importing the file to execute the statement.

Apparently, os.system("mysql -u root -ppassword") works just fine, but not the restore and dump commands. Does anyone know how to fix this or another way I can accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out that the problem was that when the user already existed, I did not commit the database, which resulted in the connection not closing, and when I tried to create another one (i.e. used the mysql command), the latter waited forever for the first to end.

To prevent this: either commit or close a connection to the database, or close the cursor before creating another connection to the database (or use the same cursor to restore).